# Problems creating Stack! (arcade game) in C++

Tags: c++, console-application

im a beginner amateur in C++ and i recently had the idea to remake the popular arcade game Stack! in the C++ console.
The problem occours when the player has got to place the pad:
the pad places well, but if you make an error it doesn't resize properly (you'll understand better when you'll run the code).

Don't care about the graphic that sometimes bugs, because i can fix that on my own.
Please help me!

---

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool bDirection = true;       /* Bool for the direction:
                             true = dx, false = sx */
string sPad;
int nPadLenght = 6;
int x = 40, y =21;            // Referement tile's  position

int nSpeed = 200;
bool loop = true;             // main loop
int nScore = 0;               // score

int nPlaceX = 40;                        

int nTileX = 35, nTileY = 20; // Player's actual postition
int nEndTileX, nEndTileY;

void RenderLine(int *x, int *y);
int main();

// Void for the coordinates

void gotoxy (int x, int y){

COORD coord;
coord.X = x ;
coord.Y = y ;
SetConsoleCursorPosition (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);

}

void Victory(){

x = 10;
y = 4;

Beep(698.5, 300);
Beep(698.5, 100);
Beep(1047, 500);

system("color a");
gotoxy(x,y); cout << "You win!\n\n      Score = " << nScore;
system("pause >nul");


}


void PadLenght(int *x){

// Each number is equal to a possible pad lenght

switch (*x){

    case 6:
        sPad = "[][][]";
        nEndTileX = nTileX + 5;
        break;

    case 5:
        sPad = "[][]]";
        nEndTileX = nTileX + 4;
        break;

    case 4:
        sPad = "[][]";
        nEndTileX = nTileX + 3;
        break;

    case 3:
        sPad = "[][";
        nEndTileX = nTileX + 2;
        break;

    case 2:
        sPad = "[]";
        nEndTileX = nTileX + 1;
        break;

    case 1:
        sPad = "[";
        nEndTileX = nTileX;
        break;

}
}

void SwitchDirection(bool *x){

// Switches the bool of the direction

switch (*x){

    case true:
        *x = false;
        break;

    case false:
        *x = true;
        break;

}

}

void Speed(){

// For each line from 500ms to 20ms speed increments of 10ms

if (nSpeed > 20)
    nSpeed -= 20;

}

// void for placing the pad

void Place() {

int i = nPlaceX - nTileX;

if (i < 0)
    i * -1;

nPadLenght -= i;



}

void collision(){

    // Collisions with the border

    if (nTileX > 45 || nTileX < 35)
    SwitchDirection(&bDirection);

}

void movement(){

    int nLastX = nTileX;

    // Place the pad if pressing down arrow

    if(GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x8000){

    nTileY--;
    Place();
    Speed();

    Beep(698.5, 50);
    Beep(880.0, 50);
    Beep(1047, 50);

    nScore += 10;
    Sleep(60);

 }

    // Movement of the pad

    switch (bDirection){

        case true:
            gotoxy (nLastX, nTileY); cout << "                          ";          
            nTileX++;
            break;

        case false: 
            gotoxy (nLastX - nPadLenght, nTileY); cout << "                ";                                
            nTileX--;
            break;

    }


}


int main(){

system("color 0");

while (loop = true){

    char a = '"';
    gotoxy(x,y); cout << a << a << a << a << a << a;
    collision();
    PadLenght(&nPadLenght);
    movement();
    gotoxy (nTileX, nTileY); cout << sPad;
    Sleep (nSpeed);

    if (nScore > 160) {
        Victory();
        break;
    }


}



return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why are you passing by pointer in `PadLength`?  You code would be more efficient if you passed by copy.  You don't modify the `x` value so no need for pointer.  Also, you may want to label it as `const` to show the reader that the argument is not modified.  This goes for all your functions requiring a parameter.  Pass by value, when the variable is not modified and pass by reference when it needs to be modified.

Comment: You can also use more math:  `nEndTileX = nTileX + x - 1;`, this will reduce the amount of code in your `PadLength` function (note the spelling correction).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some issues I found:

### "using namespace std;"

This is bad.  This brings in **all** of the identifier names from the `std` namespace.  The preference is to use the `std` prefix (e.g. `std::cout`) or choose from the `std` namespace, (e.g. `using std::cout;`).

### Global variables

Prefer to not have global variables.  Create them in `main` and pass them to functions.
For example, you have global `x` and `y`, and you use `x` and `y` as parameters in functions.  This may lead to confusion between you, readers and the compilers, as to which variables *you* are referring to.

### Passing by pointer

Prefer not to use pointers.
Pass by value (without pointers) for variables that can fit into a processor's register, like `float, double, int, bool` and `char`.
For classes and structures, pass by reference.  If you are not modifying the parameter, pass by constant reference.

### Don't create functions for simple content

Functions require an overhead to execute, usually at least 3 instructions (save parameters, branch to function, return from function).  Some operations can be performed with less statements:

```
// Switch directions:
direction = ! direction;
```

If you *must* use functions, give the compiler the hint that you want them `inline`.  This means that the compiler will paste the content of the function where the function call is made.  Some compilers may do this for optimizations, but you have to tell the compiler to optimize.

### Boolean `switch` statements

Switch statements are kind of overkill for Boolean varibles, since there are only 2 outcomes.  Common coding guidelines are to use `if` and `else`.

### '=' in conditional expressions

Remember, one `=` for assignment, two for comparison.
The language allows for an assignment in a comparison, but most likely, you were not thinking of assignment, but testing for equality.

### Declare variables closest to usage

Make life easier on you, the compiler and reader, by declaring variables closest to where they are used.  For example, in `main`, there is a `loop` variable.  As a reader, I have to scroll to the top of your source to find the definition, when a better idea is to declare it in the `main` function, where it is used.

### One variable declaration per line

A common coding guideline is one variable per line.  Multiple lines have a negligible effect on the build time.  However, this makes modifications easier.  And when declaring pointers, reduces injected defects.  Let your compiler optimize the code, your task should be write clear (easily readable) and concise code.

### Increase the compiler's warning level

Force your compiler to turn on the warning level to its highest level.
Resolve all warnings.
A clean compilation has zero errors *and zero warnings*.
With compiler warnings at full, you would have noticed some of the issues I have identified.